# How to encode and decode characters in the right way

Tags: java, database, encoding, pervasive

I'm working on a web site in which the encoding used is `UTF-8`.
The server side is developed with Java and the database uses `Windows-1252` encoding.

How do I encode the characters correctly so they can be displayed correctly both in the database viewer and on the client side?

**EDIT**

Here is the code:

```
Class.forName("com.pervasive.jdbc.v2.Driver");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:pervasive://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/TEST","xxxx", "xxxxx");

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

String sql = "INSERT INTO MyTest (COL1, COL2) VALUES (99999, 'Ó 456789 ñÑ; ° - + ( _ . - / \\ & <' )";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

The database viewer shows: `? 456789 ??; ? - + ( _ . - / \\ & <` instead of `Ó 456789 ñÑ; ° - + ( _ . - / \\ & <`

The String `? 456789 ??; ? - + ( _ . - / \\ & <` is retrieved when `SELECT` is excecuted

Comment: From personal experience, there's not really a good way to do so without suffering some sort of losses. One possible workaround is to have your data in the database store encoded HTML entities (such as &copy; or &#8364; for the copyright logo), and expect those to show up as such in the database viewer while expecting to handle them in code on the Java side and convert them to and from the necessary formats. It's gross, but it highlights the need for Unicode-compliant database technology.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja you are confusing and conflating HTML `escaping` with Character set `byte[]` encoding which are too completely different issues.

Comment: No, I'm not. The goal here is to have displayable characters/code points working on both ends, some of which are outside of the representable range of Windows-1252, if I've understood correctly. While Unicode was designed for this in mind, it isn't allowed in Pervasive SQL servers before the most recent Version 12, therefore we need to come up with a different solution that will work in the DB viewer as well as in the Java and on the web. HTML entity encoding of non-Windows-1252-represented code points is a **workaround**, not a **solution** to this problem.

Comment: I think the problem is conflated by the fact that neither Oracle pre-10g nor Pervasive pre-v12 have *decent* JDBC implementations which properly handle situations where the underlying data is nasty (ie. represented by a single-byte code page but containing multi-byte characters, as is the case with my previous experience).

Comment: You are confusing `Unicode` codepoint specifications which is not an encoding with encodings `UTF-8`, `UTF-16` and `UTF-32` and `Windows-1252` are encodings that all represent the same `Unicode` code point mappings but slightly different. How something displays text is the problem of the client interpreting it and displaying it not the source of the data.

Comment: No, I'm not! I'm simply suggesting another "works poorly everywhere" alternative to properly handling character encodings in Java during the process of interacting with the database. It's not ideal, obviously, but it gets the work done if the actual Java code can't be touched, but the data can be.

Comment: this is a problem with the client software using the wrong encoding as I state in my answer, simple as that. but you never once tell us what client software package you are using or show us that code or the db server configuration so it is impossible to do anything but speculate.

Answer (score 1):

#### In Java `String` uses `UTF-16` internally:

If you have a plain Java `String` you do not need to do anything, your JDBC driver will convert a Java `String` to whatever encoding it uses transparently if you insert it as a `String` in your insert statement.

And when you read `ResultSet.getString()` it will give you back a Java `String` transparently.

If this is not the case then something is not configured correctly in the application and is inserting bad data that is not the encoding that it says it is. Garbage In/Garbage Out.

#### When you need to worry about encoding/decoding:

You only have to worry about translating `byte[]` encodings when reading/writing textual data to files or sockets that only accept `byte[]`.

When working with `byte[]` that represent text you need to use `new String(bytes,Charset)` and `byte[] b = string.getBytes(Charset);` respectfully  specifying whatever encoding the source/destination `String` is coming in and needs to be going out.

#### Never rely on the default encoding:

Never use `new String(byte[])` or `.getBytes()` which uses the `default` encoding which is crap shoot what you get because of all the ways that it can vary that are opaque to your code.

The subtle issue is that `UTF-8`, `Windows-1252` and a couple of other encodings are a superset of `ASCII` and overlap each other as well in this range. So if you use the `default` encoding everything might look like it is working fine and then things blow up when you ingest/export some `byte[]` that contains `non-ASCII` range characters.

#### In Summary:

1. **Never** use `byte[]` to represent text unless some API requires you to.
2. **Never** rely on the default encoding, even if you think you know what it is.
3. **Always** specify the `Charset` when converted from `byte[]` or to `byte[]`.
4. **Never** conflate or confuse `Charset` encoding with `URL/URI/HTML/XML` escaping.
5. Unicode is **not** an encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It seems to be a configuration problem. Please check the edit on the question above,